# External parameter not working in match stage of mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some documents that look something like this

```
{
  ...
  "isLive": true,
  "createdBy": "622b5e56a453be8bf6a6d290"
  ...
}
```

In my aggregation pipeline, I am trying to create a `match` stage that matches if `isLive: true` or `createdBy: userId`.

`userId` is passed in externally.

My pipeline looks something like this

```
const modelPipeline = (isAdmin, userId) => {
  const pipeline = [];

  if (!isAdmin) {
    pipeline.push({
      $match: {
        $or: [{ isLive: true }, { createdBy: userId }],
      },
    });
  }
  ...
  return Model.aggregate(pipeline);
};
```

When the documents are returned, the `isLive: true` match has worked, but the `createdBy: userId` has not.

If I `console.log(userId === "622b5e56a453be8bf6a6d290")` it returns `true`.

Is the problem something to do with it originally being an `ObjectId` maybe?

Comment: Is the `createdBy` stored as `ObjectId` or a `string` type?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

I needed to parse it as follows

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

$match: {
  $or: [{ isLive: true }, { createdBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}],
},
```